# "python setup.py egg_info" falló con el código de error 1 cuando intenté agregar flask_mysqldb

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, flask

Intenté ejecutar [una aplicación escrito con Python 3](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot) pero faltaba una biblioteca. Así que traté de instalarlo, pero tuve problemas otra vez.

```
(moodbotenv) mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/moodbot$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
ImportError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
(moodbotenv) mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/moodbot$ pip install flask_mysqldb
Collecting flask_mysqldb
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e014104/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in ./moodbotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flask_mysqldb) (1.0.2)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask_mysqldb)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-m0f55wch/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-m0f55wch/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-m0f55wch/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 28, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-m0f55wch/mysqlclient/
```

Buscando [en la red](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/418) intenté lanzar `pip install --upgrade setuptools` Pero ya está ya actualizado.

Comment: ¿Tienes `mysql` (`sudo apt-get install mysql`) y `libmysqlclient-dev` (`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`) instalados en el sistema)? Durante la instalación se necesita tener acceso a mysql_config (por lo que debe estar en el PATH) para enlazar con las libreas compiladas necesarias: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#prerequisites